# Count district values based on another coulmn

Tags: sql, vertica

I have an SQL table of people with their event attendance status:

| Person | EventStatus |
| --- | --- |
| Ethan Williams | NoShow |
| Ethan Williams | NoShow |
| Olivia Rodriguez | Arrived |
| Olivia Rodriguez | NoShow |
| Olivia Rodriguez | NoShow |
| Benjamin Chen | Arrived |
| Benjamin Chen | NoShow |
| Isabella Gomez | NoShow |

I'm trying to filter and count only the people who never came to any event but can't get the right code to do this.

I was able to get this result using this code:

```
SELECT "Person" as "Person"
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY "Person"
HAVING (((COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
                         WHEN EventStatus = 'NoShow' THEN 1
                         ELSE NULL
                     END) - COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
                         WHEN EventStatus = 'Arrived' THEN 1
                                               ELSE NULL
                                           END)) > 0))
```

But using "GROUP BY" won't allow me to count the results.

The expected result I need is: `2`
Which is the result these 2 people who are always "NoShow": Isabella Gomez, Ethan Williams.

Comment: What is the problem?  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/eEQ1KgWD )  Your query returns two names, which can be counted...

Comment: Why did you tag SQL Server. From the error messages that you get it is clear that you are using Vertica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who ***never*** showed = all people - people who ***ever*** showed.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT person)
  -
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EventStatus = 'Arrived' THEN person END)
FROM
  yourTable
```

Comment: Side note: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ... THEN somevalue END)` requires an extra sort in all cases, as the optimizer does not understand the expression to be functionally dependent on `someValue`. It's much better to create a derived table/CTE which is grouped by `someValue` and contains conditional aggregation, then sum that. Something more like @TimBiegeleisen's answer, although his doesn't give the total conditional sum.

Comment: @Charlieface Same concerns apply to `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN EventStatus = 'Arrived' THEN 1 END) = 0`, your reasoning only holds if using `MIN()` or another order based function. Also, the correct sort order for the `COUNT(DISTINCT person)` happens to be a *good* sort order for the `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE)`

Comment: No it doesn't. `COUNT(CASE WHEN...` does not require a sort if the `GROUP BY` columns are indexed, as the index can be scanned in order of the grouping. Whereas `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN...` requires a sort to satisfy the `DISTINCT`. So the way to get around that is to group twice, both times will be in index order. There is simply no understanding in the optimizer to work out that the `CASE` is functionally dependent on the sort order (see eg https://explainextended.com/2010/02/19/things-sql-needs-sargability-of-monotonic-functions/ for how it could in theory be implemented if MS wanted to)

Comment: See this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/smIaUSai where the `DISTINCT CASE` has not only required an extra sort, it has also made an extra scan of the base table.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses aggregation along the lines of what you were trying:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Person
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Person
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN EventStatus = 'Arrived' THEN 1 END) = 0
)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get the names but unable to count them

`Severity: b'ERROR', Message: b'Aggregate function calls cannot contain subqueries'`

Comment: I didn't know you want the count rather than the individual names.  Check the updated answer.